# How to migrate from Angular 4 to Angular 5?

Tags: angular

I am new in Angular. I have created new project using Angular CLI last month, but now the new version was released.

I want to migrate my project to latest version of Angular (v5), how can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

The Angular folks have published a migration guide which gives you specific instructions about how to update your application (not only your dependencies) depending on your current version, your package manager and how complex your application is.

You can try it [here](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Updating  is as easy as updating your Angular dependencies to the latest version.

Try:

```
npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router,animations}@latest typescript@latest --save
```

install these pakages in you project.

Comment: on windows users can try this => npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save